# Append generated PDF with iText to Zip File

Tags: java, itext, zip4j

I have a Pdf generated with iText and I download it, I need to append it to a Zip file and download to, is this possible?

This is my code

```
public ActionForward descargarConstancia(ActionMapping mapping,ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){

    UsuarioBean usuarioBean = (request.getSession().getAttribute("infoUsuario") == null ? null : (UsuarioBean) request.getSession().getAttribute("infoUsuario"));
    if (usuarioBean == null) 
        return mapping.findForward("cerrarSesionNominas");
   try{
        ConstanciaRetencionBusiness constanciasBO = new ConstanciaRetencionBusinessImpl();

        UsuarioNominasBean usuarioNomBean = (request.getSession().getAttribute("usuarioNominasBean") == null ? null : (UsuarioNominasBean) request.getSession().getAttribute("usuarioNominasBean"));
        String rfcOtro = request.getParameter("rfc")!=null ? request.getParameter("rfc") : usuarioNomBean.getRFC();
        List listaConst = constanciasBO.selectByRFC(rfcOtro);
        int noConstancia = request.getParameter("noConstancia")!=null ? Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("noConstancia")) : 0;

        List lstPdfBytes = new ArrayList();
        if(listaConst!=null && listaConst.size()>noConstancia){

            ConstanciaRetencionVO vo = (ConstanciaRetencionVO)listaConst.get(noConstancia);
            lstPdfBytes.add(constanciasBO.generarConstancia(request, vo));
            response.setContentType("application/pdf");
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Constancia_"+rfcOtro+".pdf");
            OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
            concatena( lstPdfBytes, out,request);
            out.flush();
            out.close(); 

        }

    }catch(Exception e){
        log.info(LineException.getException(e));
        return mapping.findForward(mostrarRecibo);
    }finally{
    }
    return mapping.findForward("registroCorrecto");
}
```

And this is the code fo generate the PDF

```
public void concatena(List lstPdfBytes, OutputStream out,HttpServletRequest req) throws Exception{
    try{
        PdfReader reader = null;
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(document, out);
        document.open();
        for(int i=0; lstPdfBytes!=null && i<lstPdfBytes.size(); i++){
            reader = new PdfReader((byte[])lstPdfBytes.get(i));
            int paginas = reader.getNumberOfPages();
            for(int j=0; j<paginas;j++){
                copy.addPage(copy.getImportedPage(reader, j+1));
            }
        }       
        document.close();

    }catch(Exception exc){
        log.info(LineException.getException(exc));
        throw new Exception(Errores.ERROR_PDF);
    }
}
```

I was trying with Zip4j library but I'm stuck

```
        response.setContentType("application/zip");
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Constancia_"+rfcOtro+".zip");
            OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
            ConstanciaRetencionVO vo = (ConstanciaRetencionVO)listaConst.get(noConstancia);
            byte []arr=constanciasBO.generarConstancia(request, vo);

            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            concatena( lstPdfBytes, out);

            ZipParameters parametros = new ZipParameters();
            parametros.setCompressionMethod(8);
            parametros.setCompressionLevel(5);
            parametros.setEncryptFiles(true);
            parametros.setPassword("password");
            parametros.setEncryptionMethod(99);
            parametros.setAesKeyStrength(3);
            parametros.setSourceExternalStream(true);
            parametros.setFileNameInZip("constancia.pdf");

            ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(baos);
            zos.putNextEntry((File)null, parametros);
            zos.write(arr);
            zos.closeEntry();
            zos.flush();
            zos.finish();

            concatena( lstPdfBytes, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    response.setContentType("application/zip");
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Constancia_"+rfcOtro+".zip");

            ConstanciaRetencionVO vo = (ConstanciaRetencionVO)listaConst.get(noConstancia);
            byte[] arr = constanciasBO.generarConstancia(request, vo);
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ZipParameters parametros = new ZipParameters();
            parametros.setCompressionMethod(8);
            parametros.setCompressionLevel(5);
            parametros.setEncryptFiles(true);
            parametros.setPassword("password");
            parametros.setEncryptionMethod(99);
            parametros.setAesKeyStrength(3);

            parametros.setSourceExternalStream(true);
            parametros.setFileNameInZip("constancia.pdf");

            ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(baos);
            zos.putNextEntry(null, parametros);
            zos.write(arr);
            zos.closeEntry();
            zos.finish();
            zos.close();

            response.getOutputStream().write(baos.toByteArray());
            response.flushBuffer();
            baos.close();
```